# Create Pairs with respect to Date and Time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

How can I pair the two `ids` which fall in same date and time range. With same date and nearly same time (difference of 30 seconds) in both connection `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

Input Data:

```
bd5a4d8305ee951499c12b9da67d8518,2010-03-08 17:07:32.012002,2010-03-08 17:09:18.917441
85c5acd19a304c4b209f7b9f3dcff284,2010-03-08 17:07:31.924119,2010-03-08 17:07:51.083576
b4d39aa2f5997ffb5829c4f7c5823485,2010-03-08 17:07:28.226588,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
a10fd3a84ea58c998404c82d036cabeb,2010-03-08 17:07:27.549635,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
05d4b726f41268aea1bede2db213dcc6,2010-03-08 17:07:25.703349,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
e28e7b8b1c6b9c13808fa1137cf18e7b,2010-03-08 17:07:15.585748,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
c2b4dc9d47e7453c2bd117f23805f194,2010-03-08 17:07:11.898081,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
79005606569620be06f7b073c42bf65f,2010-03-08 17:06:49.592932,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
d76939f92a546e0369422c70f6cb1d0f,2010-03-08 17:06:30.368827,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
43d8ed58e5ba0a5dd6dbf917c26ea7b4,2010-03-08 17:06:07.884841,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
43e75786741c852b338c1e481d0d7029,2010-03-08 17:06:07.293614,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
```

Expected Output:

```
bd5a4d8305ee951499c12b9da67d8518,b4d39aa2f5997ffb5829c4f7c5823485,2010-03-08 17:07:32.012002,2010-03-08 17:09:18.917441
        a10fd3a84ea58c998404c82d036cabeb,05d4b726f41268aea1bede2db213dcc6,2010-03-08 17:07:27.549635,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
        e28e7b8b1c6b9c13808fa1137cf18e7b,c2b4dc9d47e7453c2bd117f23805f194,2010-03-08 17:07:15.585748,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
        79005606569620be06f7b073c42bf65f,d76939f92a546e0369422c70f6cb1d0f,2010-03-08 17:06:49.592932,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
        43d8ed58e5ba0a5dd6dbf917c26ea7b4,43e75786741c852b338c1e481d0d7029,2010-03-08 17:06:07.884841,2010-03-12 16:09:58.122987
```

Pairing up the `Ids` that have same datetime (with a maximum difference of 60 seconds or 1 minute).

When the start and end date and time are same it is possible to find the pair but when they are slightly different rounding off seems to be difficult.

I did try to look into python tutorial and also try to find some examples here but seems no luck.

Comment: Hint: round down/up to nearest second. then try minute to find matches.